# Best way to accomplish _single_ instance container CI/CD on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

My goal is to have an AWS code commit repo, that on push to main branch will run a code pipeline CI/CD process to deploy a single node app to AWS.

I went through the setup to get this working with fargate via CDK using [ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService.html), but ultimately ran into issues because the ALB requires two availability zones, and I don't want to run two instance of my app (I'm not concerned with high availability, and in this case it's a chat bot that I don't want "logged on" twice).

Does anyone have any recommendations here? Perhaps EBS is the service I want? (I've gone down that path pre-container, but maybe I should revisit?)

I also read about the code deploy agent and EC2, but that seems more of a manual process, where I'm hoping to be able to automated the creation of all resources with CDK.

---

**resolution:** I believe this is a case of me not understanding fargate well enough, shoutout @Victor Smirnov for helping break down everything for me.

There is in fact only a single task registered when my CDK stack builds.

I think the issue I ran into was I'd use the CDK codepipeline ECS deploy action, which would start deploying a second task before deregistering the first (which I think is just a fargate "feature" to avoid downtime, ie blue/green deploy). I mistakenly expected only a single container to be running at a given time, but that's just not how Services work.

I think Victor had a good point about the health checks as well. It took me a few tries to get all the ports lined up, and when they were misaligned and health checks were failing I'd see the "old failed task" getting "deregistered" alongside the "new task that hadn't failed yet" which made me think I had two concurrent tasks running.

Comment: " ASG requires two availability zones" - no, that's not the case. Maybe you are confusign ASG with load balancer (ALB)?

Comment: Yea I think you're right, I probably meant ALB. When I used CDK I created a `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService`, which seemed to create a target group in EC2 under "Load Balancing" that was trying to poll two instances (despite there only being 1 running instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example of the `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService` pattern used to create the Fargate service with one running task. I deployed the stack when I wrote the answer to the question.

The Application load balancer has three availability zones because my VPC has three public subnets. It means that the loader balancer itself has the IP addresses in three different zones.

[image]

The load balancer has only one target. There is no requirement that the load balancer should have a target in each zone.

[image]

I put everything in the public VPC zone because I do not have NAT. You might want to have your Fargate tasks in the private zone for better security.

I added the health check path with default values because, most likely, you will want to define a custom URL for your service. We can omit the default definition.

```js
import { App, RemovalPolicy, Stack } from 'aws-cdk-lib'
import { Certificate, CertificateValidation } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-certificatemanager'
import { Vpc } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2'
import { Cluster, ContainerImage, LogDriver } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs'
import { ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs-patterns'
import { ApplicationProtocol } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2'
import { LogGroup } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-logs'
import { HostedZone } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-route53'
import { env } from 'process'

function createStack (scope, id, props) {
  const stack = new Stack(scope, id, props)

  const logGroup = new LogGroup(stack, 'LogGroup', { logGroupName: 'so-service', removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY })

  const vpc = Vpc.fromLookup(stack, 'Vpc', { vpcName: 'BlogVpc' })

  const domainZone = HostedZone.fromLookup(stack, 'ZonePublic', { domainName: 'victorsmirnov.blog' })

  const domainName = 'service.victorsmirnov.blog'
  const certificate = new Certificate(stack, 'SslCertificate', {
    domainName,
    validation: CertificateValidation.fromDns(domainZone)
  })

  const cluster = new Cluster(stack, 'Cluster', {
    clusterName: 'so-cluster',
    containerInsights: true,
    enableFargateCapacityProviders: true,
    vpc,
  })

  const service = new ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(stack, id, {
    assignPublicIp: true,
    certificate,
    cluster,
    cpu: 256,
    desiredCount: 1,
    domainName,
    domainZone,
    memoryLimitMiB: 512,
    openListener: true,
    protocol: ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
    publicLoadBalancer: true,
    redirectHTTP: true,
    targetProtocol: ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
    taskImageOptions: {
      containerName: 'nginx',
      containerPort: 80,
      enableLogging: true,
      family: 'so-service',
      image: ContainerImage.fromRegistry('nginx'),
      logDriver: LogDriver.awsLogs({ streamPrefix: 'nginx', logGroup })
    }
  })

  service.targetGroup.configureHealthCheck({
    path: '/',
  })

  return stack
}

const app = new App()
createStack(app, 'SingleInstanceAlbService', {
  env: { account: env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT, region: env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION }
})
```

Content for the `cdk.json` and `package.json` for completeness.

```json
{
    "app": "node question.js",
    "context": {
        "@aws-cdk/core:newStyleStackSynthesis": true
    }
}
```

```json
{
    "name": "alb-single-instance",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "aws-cdk-lib": "^2.37.1",
        "cdk": "^2.37.1",
        "constructs": "^10.1.76"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
        "snazzy": "^9.0.0",
        "standard": "^17.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "cdk": "cdk",
        "clean": "rimraf cdk.out dist",
        "format": "standard --fix --verbose | snazzy",
        "test": "standard --verbose | snazzy"
    },
    "type": "module"
}
```

This should be enough to have a fully functional setup where everything is configured automatically using the CDK.

Maybe you do not need the load balancer because there is no need to balance traffic for only one task. You can set up the Service discovery for your service and use the DNS name for your task without a load balancer. This should save money if you want.

Comment: Super helpful, thank you so much for this <3 I will take a look this evening and see where my CDK config might deviate from what you have. I would be curious to know if under the EC2 > Load Balancing > Target Groups you have a single target that the health checks are running against (vs one for each of your AZs). Thank you again really appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: Yes, only one target group. Load balancer might have any number of target groups (0, 1, 2, ...). Every target group might have a different number of targets. A health check is a property of a target group. Load balancer runs the same health checks for all targets inside the target group. If the check fails, then the ALB marks the target as unhealthy. As a result, the ECS cluster destroys the unhealthy target and launches a new one. Let me know if you want a picture for this. p.s. I am working on my writing skills, so I will try to explain everything crystal clear as an exercise :)

Comment: No picture required, thank you for the explanation. I will spin up your stack this evening and confirm the output. With my stack I was getting a single target group, but it had _two_ targets in it (the second of which seemed to fail health checks). I imagine this is something related to my setup, so I'll do some digging before troubling you further. Thank you again, if I can buy you a coffee or something for the trouble let me know, my email is don at cranburi dot com.

Comment: I think I understand :) When the target fails, the ECS launches a new one. Check the logs for your task. Or check the tasks for the service. I guess you will see many stopped tasks. It takes some time to deregister unhealthy tasks. This is why you see two tasks in the targets list. I had the issue many times. It is super annoying when this happens during the first deployment because you have to stop the deployment and delete everything. In a nutshell, make sure your health check can run on the target.

Comment: Victor you were right on, thanks again for all the help

Answer (score 1):

Your application can still be in one AZ. The fact that ALB requires two AZs is only related to ALB itself. So you do not have to create any extra instance of your application in other AZ if you don't want. Though it could be a good idea for high-availability.

Comment: Appreciate your time, it seemed like by default the "health checks" were trying to hit two separate instances (in two different availability zones), but since I had configured Fargate for only a "desiredCount" of 1, the second health check was always failing.


Perhaps I should focus on trying to reconfigure things to avoid the second health check? (as opposed to thinking Fargate isn't the right tool here)

Comment: @Don health checks wouldn't be trying to hit some non-existent instance. More likely it is the fact that the health checks are running in both AZs, and I'm guessing you have some security group rule blocking traffic from one of the AZs to your ECS task?

Comment: I'm using the CDK so most of that stuff is wired up for me, I will check the SG rules. I did notice that there were two tasks running in the service (which I think would indicate there were two "containers" running?) but when I'd look under EC2 I'd normally see one health check passing, and one failing (the one to use-1b, aka a second AZ). I spent a bunch of time reading last night and it sounds like maybe for the use case of "I just want a single instance of this container running" I should prefer a Fargate "Task" (as opposed to a Service with load balancing).